# What's the deal with Ramsey graph theory with vertex-colourings instead of edge-colourings?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

As in the edge-colouring case, we can talk of a $r$-Ramsey graph $R$ for some (finite) graph $G$ wrt. vertex-colouring, i.e. such that for every $r$-colouring of the vertices of $R$ there is a copy of $G$ in $R$ with all the vertices having the same colour.

Existence is immediate from pigeonhole and many issues analogous to those in the edge-coluring case seem to admit quick elementary answers (unless one considers the induced setting). What's more, literature on this seems to be sparse and doesn't seem to do much beyond trying to establish some necessary conditions for Ramseyness in the edge-colouring case. This makes me wonder:

What are some notable results and references in Ramsey theory for graphs wrt. vertex colourings? Are the issues fundamentally different from the edge-colouring case or are they just easy to answer and reducible to something trivial in general, which renders the whole concept uninteresting?

I would appreciate any bits and pieces of wisdom on this!